# loadchunk true lazy loading problem angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using ngx element & loadchildren  , when I load my page I have this error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"loadChunkError":true)

any idea?

```
{
    selector: 'app-ordering',
    loadChildren: () => import(
      /* webpackChunkName: `al-ordering` */
      './features/ordering/ordering.module')
      .then(m => m.OrderingModule, () => { throw ({ loadChunkError: true }); })
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lazy loading and just navigating to your module normally. This should surface a more helpful error. Then once you have that fixed you can flip back to lazy loading.

Alternatively you may be able to get away with something like this to surface a more informative error,

```
.then(m => m.OrderingModule, (err) => { throw e; })
```